# Symfony Dependency injection serivces.yaml configurtion by interface

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'm looking for solution of my problem.
I wonder if i can do something like this:

```
 App\Product\Domain\ProductSaver: '@App\Product\Infrastructure\Saver\ProductJsonSaver'
```

But i want to use it too:

```
 App\Product\Domain\ProductSaver: '@App\Product\Infrastructure\Saver\ProductORMSaver'
```

Depends of which User Interface call it.

For example if i call **/product/save/database endpoint** i want to use ProductORMSaver and if i call **/product/save/file endpoint** i want to use ProductJsonSaver. Is it possible? I found solution which rely on parameter name but i want to avoid it.

Comment: Nope.  Service ids must be unique.  Plus there would be no way to for the container to know which to use.  Either manually define your endpoint services or just have them directly typehint against ProductJsonSaver or ProductORMSaver.  I suppose you could also take a look at [service locators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html).  Basically end up injecting a ProductSaverLocator and then each endpoint would pull the one they need.

Comment: So i if i understand you properly i should do something like this to distiguish objects
   App\Product\Domain\ProductSaver $productORMSaver: '@App\Product\Infrastructure\Saver\ProductORMSaver'

    App\Product\Domain\ProductSaver $productJsonSaver: '@App\Product\Infrastructure\Saver\ProductJsonSaver'

Comment: Well no.  First off, consider editing your question whenever you have the urge to use code in comments.  As you can see, comments do not format effectively.  Secondly, you are either overthinking the problem or trying to solve something else completely.  database_endpoint(ProductORMSaver $productSaver) is all you need.  No need for aliases at all.

Comment: Shouldnt I inject by abstraction (interface)? D from SOLID.

Comment: Using interfaces is generally a good thing however autowire assumes that there is a single implementation of a given interface.  So your choice is basically to inject concrete implementations using autowire or manually defining your services.

Comment: Thank you so much, i think i know enought to move further.